# Swift- JSON Requests with more than one page

Tags: json, swift, youtube-api, alamofire, swifty-json

I am using Alamofire and SwiftyJSON to access Youtube's API and get a channels's playlist count. My problem is that Youtube returns only 5 items per page (or request) and I don't know how to access the rest!

```
func getPlaylists() {
    Alamofire.request(.GET, playlistURL).validate().responseJSON { response in
        switch response.result {
        case .Success:
            if let value = response.result.value {
                let json = JSON(value)
                print(json["items"].count) //Always returns 5
            }
        case .Failure(let error):
            print(error)
        }
    }
}
```

Can anybody let me know how to access the next set of results?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll find the answer in the API documentation, possibly here [YouTube Data API](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/playlists/list).

Note: in your request, you can set the max items per page with a query parameter: `maxResults`. This can be 5 to 50, default equals 5.

When you get a response, the server returns a JSON containing a JSON value `"nextToken": <string>`. Use this value in your next request, where you insert a query parameter `pageToken=<string>`.

You might modify your `getPlaylists` method so that it takes a parameter `nextToken: String`. Initially call this method with an empty string or better an optional initialized to `nil`.

In your completion handler, retrieve the `"nextToken"` value from the JSON response. If it exists, call your method with this parameter. Otherwise, you got all pages.

Your method `getPlaylists` should also have a completion handler. Call the completion handler when all pages have been retrieved.